# Checking individual pixels in a bitmap, how to store the bitmap?

Tags: android

I'm doing an application where I need to detect if the user is selecting a longitude/latitude pair that's on land or at sea on a MapView. I could get this answered by sending a request to the Google Maps service, but I'd rather it work offline too. So I've come up with two ways that this could function, and since I'm rather green on the Bitmap vs. memory area I thought I'd get your input.

The main idea is that I'm storing a small black and white bitmap of the map area I want to cover (say 200x200 px). When a user selects a longitude/latitude pair, then that pair is converted into a set of x,y pixels and I check if the pixel coordinates points to a black pixel(land) or a white pixel(sea/water). Here's the two methods I've come up with so far.

**Option A**

Lazy load the Bitmap when the user is about to select the long/lat pair and use [`getPixel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29) to check if it's at land or sea. Keep a WeakReference to the image at let it be garbage collected whenever the GC comes around.

**Option B**

Keep each pixel coordinate pair of the bitmap in a SQLite database and do a lookup everytime the user is about to select a long/lat pair.

I'm guessing that **A** is the best one speed-wise (ignoring the overhead of reading the bitmap from the disk in the first place), but is it costly to keep the bitmap in memory, battery-wise?

If you have any other suggestions on how to do this then I would love to here them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, option A is fastest but, I am confused as to why you think that using a bitmap will impact battery.

All of the memory in your phone always holds a 1 or a 0.  There is a very small difference in power (and I mean small) between a 1 and a 0 but across hundreds of megabytes, or gigs, of memory, we can assume a random 50/50 distribution of 1s and 0s.  The memory you load your bitmap into was full of 1s and 0s before you load it and full of 1s and 0s after you load it.  I suspect, without measuring, that the impact of loading the bitmap from memory (since this does use power as opposed to simply keeping it loaded) is much less than the equivalent number of memory reads the SQL approach would use.

Therefore, my conclusion is that keeping the bitmap loaded has no impact on battery and option A is preferred.

[EDIT]
Having thought some more about your question, are you actually asking "which uses more power", reading a pixel from a loaded bitmap or querying a SQLite table"?

Comment: Well I'm asking about each options impact on various things like speed and battery, so the question is very valid. But by reading your answer I can see that the SQLite approach would require more processing power and thus battery.

Comment: Definitely.  To read a single pixel, the memory I/Os will be in the calculation of that pixels position in the bitmaps matrix, the retrieval of the pointer to the matrix, the creation of the pointer to the pixel then a single read of a block of bytes (the pixel itself) which will happen in one cycle.  If we assume that the amount of calculation and pointer retrieval/manipulation is the same for both, and I suspect it would actually be a lot more for a SQL query, then the number of "disk" I/Os alone suggests that the loaded bitmap approach is much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I'm a bit confused about your note on memory and perfomance. I've always thought that keeping huge objects in memory would have an impact on battery-life, like there was some sort division between "active" memory (that is, memory being used) and inactive memory. But you're saying that maxing out the allocated memory for an application has absolutely no impact on battery-life (if looking at the effects of memory only)?

Comment: Your memory is always "maxxed out".  The only question is does it contain anything that the OS and it's apps can use?

Comment: Okay I think I'm with you here. Thanks again.

Comment: Last comment, I promise :)  It's not what's in memory that costs, it's how often you read/write it.